# Waterproof Watch case?

Tags: apple-watch, third-party, case

I am looking at getting a tough armor spigen case, and I hear the Watch can survive a shower. The spigen case seems to cover all but the Digital Crown. I am not comfortable even with rain on the watch unless I can swim with it. Assuming I use this case, about how far under water can I go if at all? And is there a better option?

Comment: See the end of my question (in particular, the links) at http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/198670/what-are-current-and-any-publicly-announced-planned-water-resistances-to-the-wa .

Comment: Why was my edit to remove the  character reverted? It doesn't display properly on non-mac systems. (See [How can I display the  (U+F8FF, Apple logo) character on Windows?](https://superuser.com/q/1205451/358766))

Comment: it was reverted because the  character is the correct way to name the product.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of people have had the same concern. I know [someone tested this thoroughly](http://9to5mac.com/2015/05/11/apple-watch-waterproof/). I wouldn't do what he did, but I wouldn't be so worried, though I can't say I've taken my Apple Watch into the shower yet.

[This upcoming case from Lunatik](http://epikwatch.com/) may work as far as cases go. You can watch their Kickstarter video [here](https://goo.gl/ZvdFnU). However, I don't believe there are any other casing options that also offer waterproofing.

You also asked about alternatives. [Liquipel](http://www.liquipel.com/shop/treatment/treat-my-phone/), which is a nano-coating that would protect your watch from water damage ([they call it Watersafe](http://www.iclarified.com/44125/liquipel-will-waterproof-the-apple-watch)), seems like a viable option. [There are plenty of articles about it online](https://www.google.com/search?q=liquipel+apple+watch&oq=liquipel+apple+watch&aqs=chrome.0.69i59.9402j0j4&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=119&ie=UTF-8). The only strange thing about it is that after late September, the articles seem to disappear. I haven't been able to find anything following that date.

Unfortunately, I couldn't find specs detailing how deep one would be able to go with either protection. Regardless, the Epik Watch from Lunatik seems like the most resistant or safe option at the moment, given their video and the lack of information on Liquipel. If Liquipel is still around, and you're willing to dish out the cash (it's a pricey combo to some extent with Liquipel for iPhone going for $60 and the Epik Watch going for $100), perhaps using both wouldn't be a bad idea.

Comment: I can say that I have worn my Apple Watch in the shower once (I was in a hurry and forgot I had it on) - I haven't found any damage and everything still works fine, but I don't think I'll risking it again.

Comment: @ajkblue Did it have a case or any sort of screen protector on? I have a KlearKare plastic screen protector on mine, which is great for keeping away for scratches. I wonder if it would at all enhance how water proof the Epik Watch sounds like it is.

Comment: I do not have a case or screen protector for my Watch.