# Can I run with an Apple Watch in the rain?

Tags: apple-watch

I'm starting to feel that none of the Apple Watch designers actually broke a sweat while working out with the watch, nor did they try to exercise in the rain.

I started the Workout app on Outdoor Run, then at about a mile into my run I pulled back my rain-soaked sleeve to find that my workout was stopped about half a mile back, I assume because the water was mistaken for touch input.

With my Garmin Forerunner I could lock the touch bezel but continue to use the side buttons to start, stop, and reset the timer.

Am I missing a similar feature on the Apple Watch?

Comment: The Apple Watch has a water resistance rating of "IPX7 under IEC standard 60529," which means it can be submerged in 3.3 feet of water for up to 30 minutes.

Comment: @IconDaemon read the whole question, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to turn the touch input off temporarily, but you can prevent the Apple Watch from stopping workouts early. When you start a workout just go to the watch face the way you normally would, the Workout will run in the background and can't be stopped until you go back to the app and it stop it yourself. It's not perfect, as you can't see your live progress, but it still works.

Comment: I tried this today, but every time I raised my wrist it brought back the workout app, even though I have Activate On Write Raise set to "Show Watch Face" and not "Resume Previous Activity". I guess I should disable Wrist Detection completely, because even if it did show the watch face, water could still trigger the complications.

Comment: That's very weird. It works just fine for me. I went into Workouts, started a workout, and then double-clicked the Crown to get back to the watch face. I lowered and raised my wrist multiple times at different intervals, and it always shows the watch face.

Answer (score 2):

This question might be very old, but could still be relevant to some.  However the answers are not up to date:

> To lock the screen while doing an activity, swipe to the right so that the menu shows.  In this menu select "Lock" which has the water drop icon.

Now the watch is locked in the same matter as during a swimming activity: to unlock the watch turn the crown for a second or two.

Answer (score 0):

This might be something that was added in Watch OS2... You can lock your watch screen when you are using the Workout app.

The basics of this are launch the Workout app, start your workout, then force press, then you can lock the display.  To stop your workout, force press again, and select the option (end, pause, unlock).

Full instructions can be found at [this link](http://www.imore.com/how-lock-apple-watchs-screen-during-workout)

Comment: Please don't send people off-site for the answer (links may break), it's better to include the essential parts of the answer directly into your post here.